# need code help to show all attributes on Product Archives page in woocommerce shop

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming, custom-wordpress-pages, wordpress-shortcode

In my woocommerce archive page i would to show all the attributes for each product on the catalog page just below each item. i had it coded in before but our server got compromised and i couldn't recover any of the old code from the functions.php

[Picture of current archive page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kj0S8.jpg)
[all the attributes i need to show up](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LwmlX.png)

i have tried to find the past posts but i cannot find it.

i dont know or understand enough about writing code from scratch to attempt it on my own.

Comment: Can you please post pictures instead of links?  Many people post links to try to distribute malware so nobody clicks them.

Comment: if you upvote my question my reputation will be high enough to embed photos instead of linking them

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.